# Extract and update URLs in HTML string through powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this string (hundreds of them actually) containing URLs and I would like to update them.

**Here's the old URL format**
`http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=NEEDED_VALUE&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere`

**and here's what I need them to look like after the update**
`http://newDomain/c/d/NEEDED_VALUE`

Pretty much all I needed to do was to extract the value of `p2` in the old URL and append it to `http://newDomain/c/d/` to create the new URL.

**I assumed the string I was going to get would look like this:**

```
$s = "http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=001&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere,
      http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=002&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere,
      http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=003&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere"
```

**and I was able to update it using the following:**

```
$newURLStart = "http://newDomain/c/d/"
$newStr = $null
$s.Split(",") | ForEach {
  if ($_.IndexOf("p2=") -ne 1)
  {
    $neededValue = $_.Substring($_.IndexOf("p2=")+3)
    if ($neededValue.IndexOf("&") -ne -1)
    {
      $neededValue = $neededValue.Substring(0,$neededValue.IndexOf("&"))
    }
    $newStr = $newStr + ", " + $newURLStart + $neededValue
  }
}
$newStr = $newStr.TrimStart(", ")
$s = $newStr
```

**BUT, it turns out that the string I'm going to get isn't plaintext and would actually look something like:**

```
$s = '<div class="someClass"><p>SomeText</p><ul>
      <li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=001&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=002&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK TWO</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=003&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK THREE</a></li>
      </ul></div>'
```

This is a bit more complex than my comma-delimited expectations! I need help updating my script to accommodate the fact. I'm thinking regex might come into play here to grab the URLs inside the `href` but I'm pretty *noob* when it comes to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you threw all the strings in a file you could do something like so:

`Get-Content "testregex.html" | % {$_ -replace 'href=".+?;.+?=(.+?)&amp;(.+?)"', 'href="http://newdomain/c/$1"'} | Set-Content "newtestregex.html"`

Takes as input this file:

```
<div class="someClass"><p>SomeText</p><ul>
      <li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=001&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=002&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK TWO</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=003&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK THREE</a></li>
      </ul></div>
```

Yields:

```
<div class="someClass"><p>SomeText</p><ul>
      <li><a href="http://newdomain/c/001">LINK ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://newdomain/c/002">LINK TWO</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://newdomain/c/003">LINK THREE</a></li>
      </ul></div>
```

Comment: Great solution as this doesn't depend on the structure of the input itself! I'm taking this one. Thanks!

Comment: I've modified the first parameter of `-replace` to `'href=".+?p2=(.+?)&amp;(.+?)"'` in the event that the parameters aren't in order.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your input somewhat, but here it is. (BTW please please store this regex in a post-it next to your desk - it helps me again and again! :) )

I make the following assumptions:

- that the input URL is present only within

  tags

  that the URI always contains the arguments (p1 and p2)

Code:

```
# Heres the input. 
# I assume you can figure out how to extract the <li> tags from your input

$ip = '<li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=001&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=002&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK TWO</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&amp;p2=003&amp;morePsHere=moreVsHere">LINK THREE</a></li>
'

# loop through each line.
$ip -split "`n" | foreach {

        $_ -match "(?<=p2=).*(?=&amp;)"
        $matches
        # now insert the logic to put the regex match into your destination URL
}
```

More info on the regex used (and [a web result](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html)):

- The `-match` operator puts the regex match in a variable called $matches.
- In above code, $matches is updated in each line of the string.
- The `(?<=p2=)` and `(?=&amp;)` tell Powershell that it should look for a match that is bounded by the expressions `p2=` and `&amp;`. In this case its your match.

Heres the output for `$match`

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              001
0                              002
0                              003
0                              003
```

Comment: This idea works too, but again with the input string being variable, it will take more effort in looking for the `li`s and putting it all back together. *Sticky*-ing the regex though :D

Answer (score 1):

You can make this a bit easier by using Powershell's excellent XML capabilities. First, convert your string into xml: `$xmlData = [xml] $s`. Now, we can simply navigate it using properties: `$xmlData.div.ul.li.a.href` will go into the html you got, and automatically expand into collections as needed:

```
PS C:\Users\carlpett> $xmlData.div.ul.li.a.href
http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&p2=001&morePsHere=moreVsHere
http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&p2=002&morePsHere=moreVsHere
http://oldDomain/a/b/document.aspx?p1=v1&p2=003&morePsHere=moreVsHere
```

Now, it's just a simple regex to do the actual replacement: `$xmlData.div.ul.li.a.href -replace 'http:\/\/oldDomain\/.+p2=([^&]+).+','http://newDomain/c/d/$1'`

So, wrapping it up:

```
$xmlData = [xml] $s
$xmlData.div.ul.li.a.href -replace 'http:\/\/oldDomain\/.+p2=([^&]+).+','http://newDomain/c/d/$1'
```

Comment: I like this idea, but the HTML string input is *variable*, and there could be nested `ul`s in it. Nonetheless, I'll try making use of this `[xml]` trick more often. Thanks!

Comment: @kei: It is a nice trick indeed. You could actually just remove all that niceness and run the `-replace` over `$s` instead, if you want something more general.